# Can I write css in App.css or Index.css instead of creating a separate css file for my MERN project?

Tags: css, reactjs, mern

Does writing css in index.css or app.css can affect my project in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write CSS styles in App.css or index.css instead of creating a separate CSS file for your MERN project.

But , It will become messy at the end and it also not good practice.

Here's an example of how you can use App.css or index.css to write CSS styles:

Create an App.css or index.css file in your project's src directory.

Add your CSS styles to the respective file. For example:

```
    /* App.css */

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* index.css */

#root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Import the CSS file in your App.js or index.js file:

```
 import React from 'react';
import './App.css'; // or import './index.css';

function App() {
  // Your component code...
}

export default App;
```

You can upvote my answer if its helpful, thanks !!

Comment: hi, thank you for taking time to offer your knowledge to others that need help.
I would suggest you to add also a small code snippet to make the response even more clear.
thank you